# Unable to catch exception before generating a report by nbug

Tags: c#-4.0

In C#  I am Unable to catch exceptions  before catching the exception through catch block  nbug is handling it as unhandled exception and error report is generated

```
            if (components != null)
                try
                {
                    components.Dispose();//here the exception is occurring but not moving into catch, nbug is generating error report 
                }
            catch
                {
                    return;
                }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
```

Comment: try to define your type of exception and catch it in your catch block. the thing is a general exception is thrown and nbug catch it before your code. let me know if that kinda solve your issue, if yes - I'll post an answer.

Comment: Another option is to remove the NBug assignments from the Appdomain exceptions by creating a new event handler and assign the NBug to it.